# Tar creating a file that is unexpectedly large

Tags: unix, tar

Figured maybe someone here might know whats going on, but essentially what I have to do is take a directory, and make a tar file omitting a subdir two levels down (root/1/2). Given it needs to work on a bunch of platforms, the easiest way I thought was to do a find and egrep that directory out, which works well giving me the list of files.

But then I pipe that file list into a `xargs tar rvf` command and the resulting file comes out something like 33gb. I've tried to output the find to a file, and use `tar -T` with that file as input, its still comes out to about 33gb, when if I did a straight tar of the whole directory (not omitting anything) it comes in where I'd expect it at 6-ish gb.

Any thoughts on what is going on? Or how to remedy this? I really need to get this figured out, I'm guessing it has to do with feeding it a list of files vs. having it just tar a directory, but not sure how to fix that.

Comment: post the command line or script that you are running.

Comment: Can you show command line you are using to create your tar?

Comment: Sure thing, guess I should have had that from the start. Tried from piping, given I'm looking for the contents of the 'suite' dir, but without suite/tmp/Shared: 
`rm archive.tar; find suite -print|egrep -v "suite/tmp/Shared/*"|xargs tar rvf archive.tar`
And with writing to a file and then using it as input:
`find suite -print|egrep -v "suite/tmp/Shared/*">list.txt; tar cvf archive.tar -T list.txt`
Both of these give an archive.tar around 33gb

Comment: so take one of your 33 gb tar files to a separate mount point/machine, install it and see how it is different. I'm guessing that somehow you're duplicating files in your tar. Are there any spaces in the names of your dir or filenames? search here for `find . ... -print0 | xargs -0` solutions. That should eliminate any problems with spaces (or other) in file/dirs. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your find command will return directories as well as files

Consider using find to look for directories and to exclude some

```
tar cvf /path/to/archive.tar $(find suite -type d ! -name 'suite/tmp/Shared/*')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a directory in the file list, `tar` packages the directory and all the files in it.  If you then list the files in the directory separately, it packages the files (again).  If you list the sub-directories, it packages the contents of each subdirectory again.  And so on.

If you're going to do a files list, make sure it truly is a list of files and that no directories are included.

```
find . -type f ...
```

The ellipsis might be `find` options to eliminate the files in the sub-directory, or it might be a `grep -v` that eliminates them.  Note that `-name` normally only matches the last component of the name.  GNU `find` has `! -path '*/subdir/*'` or variants that will allow you to eliminate the file based on path, rather than just name:

```
find . -type f ! -path './root/1/2/*' -print
```